# GUI Design Guide paticularly for qt

Tags: qt

I wanted to know is there such a reference or documentation out there for programmer that highlight good practices for Application Design particularly GUI. I am working with a very large GUI application now (MultiThreading, Tabs, Socket Communication), it doesn't seem quite as elegant as it should be (at least feels that way, since I don't have a lot of experience).

I am particularly interested in good practices related to

- When to Use Thread? Should I use them to do computation only, handle events, etc?
- How could I make the application more flexible (ie adding more panels, or functionality possible through dynamic libraries?)
- Whats the best way to manage panels or tabs in a GUI (Singleton, Factory Classes, Object Pools)

Comment: Can you give more information on what you mean by elegant? Is it extending this GUI app with more panels that is a pain? Is it adding more features that is a pain? Is it adding more background process that is a pain?

Comment: Okay I shall elaborate more in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a book in mind, but if you want the GUI app to be flexible, you need to "centralize" the connections between the GUI and the back-end. So when a GUI component A is connected to a back-end component B, rather than connecting

```
A -> B
```

do

```
A -> GUIDispatcher -> BackendDispatcher-> B
```

GUIDispatcher always send to BackendDispatcher, while each of the dispatcher only signal to the relevant classes. It sound counter productive to add more signals and slots, but at least the control flow of your program is much more simple:

- all connections between the Gui objects and other objects are defined in the same place.
- A component in one side doesn't need to know to who he is connected on the other side, so refactoring is a bit easier.
- if there is a component which is not always enabled you don't need to handle it specifically.
- if possible send stateless data only

See [Spectrum Analyzer demo](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/05/18/qtmultimedia-in-action-a-spectrum-analyser/) in the Qt library.

Comment: Thanks, This is what I was looking for. But are there examples that use tab widget and such?

Comment: Start by looking at the demos [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/demos.html). My methodology will be to run the demo, play a bit with it and if there is a behavior I like I go inside to look at the implementation, or search for a post about it. Start by [web browser](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/demos-browser.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean GUI style guides - in which case it would depend on the platform, GUI standards for Android are different to Windows7.

Or do you mean how to structure a Qt app? Then see [Advanced-Qt-Programming-Creating-Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635906) book

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/) are the up to date docs on Qt.

If you just want the QtGui module [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtgui.html) it is.

Comment: I am more interested in learning about large software design, I am already aware of the qt documentation.